# switching views with grand central dispatch

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I've looked at a lot of topics but I still can't figure it out.

I have a UITableview which downloads its content online. Each cell has an image, and I use GCD to let the image download. The downloaded image will be saved to disk, and before each time a cell is loaded there is checked if the file already exist, if not -> gcd, nsdata etc.

All goes well if someone has a good internet connection (wifi), but if I'm going to hop from View to View (back and forth), with my crappy 3G connection, what happens is that it wants to finish its queue (about 4 cells), but already gets assigned a new one, and a new one, and a new one and eventually the user has to wait a looong time before the others are executed (which he doesnt see) before the actual UITableview gets populated. With NSLog I can see that even I'm in a different view, it's still downloading and making uiimages that were visible on the screen. Each task is approximately 100 kb, and with a slow (or even no internet connection?!) it can take a while if you have a lot.

I know it's not possible to cancel it, but I read in other topics about using a BOOL variable but I don't really get it. Even if the BOOL variable change when the user leaves the screen, the cells are already in queue right?

Is it possible that when a user taps the back button in my Navigationcontroller, so he leaves the view, I change the data the blocks in queue use (empty it), so there is nothing to download and the blocks will be executed right away (there is nothing to do). So something like, making every value in array newsitems nil? Is it possible to change the datasource, or will the blocks that are waiting already have their datasource with them while waiting?

Then there is another problem, this doesn't have effect on the the currently executed block.

Can someone point me in a good direction?

Thank you.

Prastow

Comment: So, to summarize: You are populating the represented model of a `UITableView` with a web service; and you want to cancel or pause the download queue when the user moves on to a detail view.  Is this correct?

Comment: The uitableview is populated from an online xml file, containing text and image (news feed). But the images get large so i need to do it async. I want to pause the gcd when the user goes back, so not a detailview but back to the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `NSBlockOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` to create a cancellable download task. You create an `NSBlockOperation` by giving it a block which performs some work. In your case the block would download the contents of the URL.

In your view controller, you would store a list of the operations that have been submitted to the queue. If the user decides to leave the current view, you can then call `cancel` on each of the pending operations to prevent any needless work from taking place. The currently running operation will run to completion however. In order to cancel the currently running operation, you need to store a weak reference to the NSOperation object in the block doing teh work. Then at appropriate intervals within the body of the block, you can check to see if the operation has been cancelled and exit early.

```
// Create a queue on which to run the downloads
NSOperationQueue* queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

// Create an operation without any work to do
NSBlockOperation* downloadImageOperation = [NSBlockOperation new];

// Make a weak reference to the operation. This is used to check if the operation
// has been cancelled from within the block
__weak NSBlockOperation* operation = downloadImageOperation;

// The url from which to download the image
NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someaddress.com/image.png"];

// Give the operation some work to do
[downloadImageOperation addExecutionBlock: ^() {
    // Download the image
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    // Make sure the operation was not cancelled whilst the download was in progress
    if (operation.isCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    // Do something with the image
}];

// Schedule the download by adding the download operation to the queue
[queue addOperation:imageDownloadOperation];

// As necessary
// Cancel the operation if it is not already running
[imageDownloadOperation cancel];
```

A good talk on this exact topic was given at WWDC this year entitled "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS". You can find the video and slides [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. First of all, Xcode says your code is not correct but I've fixed that. But still, nothing happens after downloadImageOperation.executionblock ?? I've put some NSLog's there but it doesn't show them.

Comment: I've fixed a bug with the code and have tested it with a sample application in Xcode. It should work now.

Comment: I get errors: "__weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable" and "Use of undeclared identifier imageDownloadOperation".

I've put this code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues with an app I developed a while back and found that the best way to do everything you require, and more, is to use https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit

It took me the best part of a day to learn and understand the conversion and then a couple more days to tweak it to exactly what I needed.

If you do decide to use it or would like a thorough overview of the capabilities start here
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/

Comment: I see a lot of topics and tutorials about grand central dispatch, especially when downloading async images for a newsfeed coming from an online xml. There should be a solution for this right?

Comment: There probably is but mknetworkkit gives you all that and it gives you automatic image/thumnail caching and loading. Download/Upload progress indications and block based execution all for free! It cut the network code I had originally wrote by 2/3 and I can handle simple requests in a couple of lines.